# Almost flat manifold crossing

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesics

Let $(M,g)$ be an almost flat Riemannian manifold with boundary, i.e. we have $diam(M,g) \leq 1$ and curvature $K \ll 1$. Let's suppose $M$ is diffeomorphic to $N \times [0,1]$ for some smooth manifold $N$ with $\partial M \cong N \times \{0\} \sqcup N \times \{1\}$.

Does the generic geodesic starting from one component of $\partial M$ eventually cross to the other component of $\partial M$ and thus exit the other side? Here I am parametrizing geodesics starting at one component of $\partial M$ by their entrance angle and asking for genericity in either the topological sense or the measure-theoretic Liouville volume sense.

This came up because I'm constructing some Riemannian manifolds by gluing along almost flat pieces and carefully smoothing the metric, but I'm wondering if I actually need to be careful at all about this smoothing in order to get this crossing property.

Edit: I'm open to taking a generic choice of almost flat metric as well, since some brief reflection suggests that the original formulation of the problem is likely false even for a cylinder...

Comment: Do you consider every annulus in $\mathbb R^2$ almost flat? If so, then there clearly exists an annulus and open set of straight lines starting with one boundary circle and existing through the same circle. This happens e.g. if the circle is not convex.

Comment: Yes, so my formulation continues to be problematic. I think the picture I have in mind is that each component of $\partial M$ is an entrance to a ``black box" which spits the geodesic back out as a random different geodesic. So what would actually be problematic in my mind is if the generic geodesic didn't cross, so that you when repeat this process over and over again you still can't get to the other side.